# Fedora "you don't have permission to view the content of root folder"

Tags: directory, root, fedora

I have installed Fedora20 on a virtual machine, and i can't open the root folder.
When i am trying to access it this message pops up
**"you don't have permission to view the content of root folder"**
as shown in the image.
[image: error message]
I am new to this so i can't figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean the root directory "/" or the actually personal folder of the root "/root".  If you mean "/" then the mask of that folder should be 755.  You can get it back to the way it should be by running from a terminal console:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /
```

From there you should be able to view the content of the root directory.  If you mean the root personal folder "/root", you're right.  You don't have access to it and probably, especially as the novice you say you are, should be careful of the area.

Using the elevated command "sudo" you can view the root directory by running:

```
$ sudo ls /root
```

If you have something very specific that you're trying to accomplish you might consider add that to the description of your question.

You might also consider showing us what command you're using in your view attempt and the exact error message you're getting, and this might help us to understand more specifically what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes i mean the **/root**, i tried your suggestion and it outputs `anaconda-ks.cfg repos`, and nothing changed. I have edited the question.

Comment: My suggestion was a console command, not gui access.  So you didn't exactly try my suggestions.  I also strongly suggest for you not to run gui browsing as root.  Some browsers run various applications on various files and file extensions (to make things convenient for the users).  If for some reason you have some type of intruder exploit some of those applications could compromise your system and cause unwanted issues.  In Windows, all users basically use the system as an elevated user.  This is why people so often have issues with Windows.  Try the "ls" command to see the files.

Comment: i tried it in terminal indeed :D. You asked to see the error message that appears.

Comment: While I'd discourage it, you could use the same "sudo" (elevated) command to run your graphic graphic file browser or (which I'd even stronger discourage, log in as root.  As far as "terminal indeed :D", I had hoped that would have resolved your issue of viewing the /root folder.  It wasn't meant to change anything, just give you a view of the content.